# Socket.io and Redis behind a load balancer.

Tags: node.js, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need socket.io to work behind a load balancer. I know, its a common question. Ive implemented:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(cfg.port, function()    {
    cfg.logger.info("Express Server listening on "+cfg.port+" for env "+cfg.environment);
}));

var adapter = require('socket.io-redis');
var pubClient = redis.createClient(cfg.redisPort, cfg.redisHost, {auth_pass: cfg.redisPW, return_buffers: true});
var subClient = redis.createClient(cfg.redisPort, cfg.redisHost, {auth_pass: cfg.redisPW, return_buffers: true});
io.adapter(adapter({pubClient: pubClient, subClient: subClient}));
```

This seems to connect fine to my redis store. I guess my question is though, is this all that needs to be implemented in order for socket.io to work with the load balancers? How would i even go about testing that this is working correctly with Elastic Beanstalk?